# How to execute code as steps using a framework or built in functionality?

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a framework or a built in way to write elegant code that is easy to maintain that does the following.

This is the example:

In my main method I want to do 3 things:

1. Buy a cake
2. Put icing on the cake
3. Serve the cake

Only once all 3 actions are complete do I consider the operation a success. 
If any one particular action fails, I want to know what failed.

To solve this problem my main method can end up looking something like this:

```
public void IsBirthdayAsuccess()
{
   var birthdayManager = new birthdayManager(); 

   try
     {
           var cake = birthdayManager.BuyCake(price.cheap, quality.good, delivery.fast);
           Assert.isTrue(cake.ArrivedQuick && cake.IsGood && cake.IsQuick, "Supplier didn't get the cake right"); 
     }
   catch
     {
          Assert.Fail("The birthday operation has failed on step 1 : Buying the cake failed"); 
     }

   try
     {
         birthdayManager.Cakes[0].PutIcingOn("Vanilla");
         Assert.IsTrue(birthdayManager.Cakes[0].IsIced(), "Icing the cake didn't work"); 

     }
   catch
     {
         Assert.Fail("The birthday operation has failed on step 2 : Putting icing on the cake");
     }

   try
     {
         Party.ServeCake(birthdayManager.Cakes[0]);
         Assert.IsTrue(birthdayManager.Cakes[0].IsServed(), "Cake couldn't be served"); 

     }
   catch
     {
         Assert.Fail("The birthday operation has failed on step 3 : Serving the cake");
     }
}
```

Now in reality, the "steps" here are represented by a series of try/catch blocks in the code, but actually elsewhere across an enterprise system. Which is why I am looking for a framework which can provide a more consistent implementation of a "steps" framework inside a function.

I was thinking of rolling my own but maybe something else exists.

If I rolled my own it would end up being something like this:

```
public void TestMethod(int id)
{
   var test = new test(id);

   TestSteps
    {
      ["Login to application"]
      TestStep
        {
            test.LoginToApplication(); 
        }
      Assert, "You are not logged in"
        {
            test.IsLoggedIn(); 
        }
      Failure
        {
            Assert.Fail("Test failed on step " + testContext.TestStep.Index); 
        }

    }
```

Does some framework like this exist?

EDIT: Also for reuse, I would be able to iterate through the "Steps" collection and the "Step" items, meaning I can use this for reporting in excel or other places.

EDIT 2: And the "roll your own" example is designed to replace the semantics of the try/catch and flow control, is C# this extendible?

Comment: Doesn't the [chain of responsability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) work on your case? [A link for .net](http://www.dofactory.com/net/chain-of-responsibility-design-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SpecFlow: http://www.specflow.org/, it is a great step-based test framework.